# PayPal Node SDKs: difference between paypal-rest-sdk and @paypal/checkout-server-sdk for webhooks?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have this question regarding 2 npm PayPal packages, what is the difference between
paypal-rest-sdk and @paypal/checkout-server-sdk ? And can you implement webhooks using  @paypal/checkout-server-sdk or there is no need for webhooks for this package ?

[paypal-rest-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/paypal-rest-sdk)

[checkout-server-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/checkout-server-sdk)

```js
var paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');

const paypal = require('@paypal/checkout-server-sdk');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `PayPal-*-SDK` for every language have been deprecated for a long time and should not be used for anything. This includes the one for node that's in npm as @paypal/paypal-rest-sdk.

The `Checkout-*-SDK` for every language, in npm for node as @paypal/checkout-server-sdk, implements the v2/checkout/orders API (and only that API). It can still be used if desired, although I've heard it will be deprecated soon as well. Currently all developer.paypal.com documentation only references doing direct HTTPS REST API integrations, using a client id and secret to first obtain an access_token. For node in particular, there is a full stack example in the [PayPal Checkout integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) that serves as a useful starting point, although I recommend the client side onApprove function in [this approval flow](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) since that sample includes client-side error handling of the capture response (restarting or showing an error as appropriate)

---

As for webhooks, they are a separate matter. There is no current SDK for them. The server-side capture API response is already sufficient for normal orders API payments so you may not need webhooks for what you're doing, but if there are specific events you're interested in listening for (such as refunds or disputes that occur on PayPal.com ) you'll need to subscribe to the [event(s) you want](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/event-names/) -- either in [the REST app](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications) or using webhook API calls.

Comment: to be honest with you my first implementation was this client side but it can be abused, I am using the check-out sdk in a firestore cloud function and after trying, throwing many wrenchs at its seems ok, on client side however a user can simply change the price of an item so in my case all of this has been done in a trusted environment using,  check-out sdk, and from here came my question, things change fast...

Comment: Corrected 2nd link above (link to server demo pattern for client-side portion of implementation).  The first link has a node sample for the server-side routes that should be good as a starting point, it also links to a sample repository I believe